# How to use notifyDataSetChanged() in recyclerview, when I have two data sources for the recyclerview, but only one data source has been changed

Tags: java, android

Currently, I have two `Lists` holding data of different types. I pass the two lists to the recyclerview's constructor. But the constructor doesn't get called on `notifyDataSetChanged()`, so how would I repopulate the `Lists` I create in the adapter's constructor, using the parameters? Also, how do I re-intialize the count variable so my little hack works?

Here's my code -

```
public class SomeAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PrefAdapter.PrefViewHolder> {

    LayoutInflater inflater;
    List<Class1> SomeList1;
    List<Class2> SomeList2;
    int count = 0;

    public PrefAdapter(Context context, List<Class1> SomeList1, List<Class2> SomeList2) {
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.SomeList1 = SomeList1;
        this.SomeList2 = SomeList2;
    }

    @Override
    public PrefViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
        return new SomeViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(SomeViewHolder holder, int position) {
        if(count >= SomeList2.size()) {
            if (nameAndNumberList.size() > 0) {
                holder.name.setText(SomeList1.get(count-SomeList2.size()).getName());
                holder.number.setText(SomeList1.get(count-SomeList2.size()).getNumber());
                count+=1;
            }
        }else {
            holder.name.setText(SomeList2.get(position).getName());
            holder.number.setText(SomeList2.get(position).getNumber());
            count+=1;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return SomeList1.size()+SomeList12.size();
    }
```

Update -

Turns out I was being really stupid. Just removed the count variable. `position` does the job of count. I need to get some sleep.

Answer (score 0):

The best idea is repopulate the data in the existing `List`.
For example:

```
SomeList1.clear();
SomeList1.addAll(list2);
```

Now invoke the `notifyDataSetChanged()`, so the data in the recyclerview's is updated

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

Comment: Where do reckon I do that? The constructor is not called when doing a `notifyDataSetChanged()`. That would work if the lists were static. Also, my `count` hack, which already doesn't work would remain that way. And I'm skeptical of the performance.

Comment: There is no need of making the lists as static, here the trick is to maintain the 'list'  reference in your Fragment/Activity. Now whenever you want to modify the recyclerView update the lists and invoke the notifyDataSetChanged(), and one more thing constructor will not be invoked when calling this method, it just recreates all the child views with the updated data in the lists.

Answer (score 0):

In your constructor, you're setting `this.SomeList1` to the `SomeList1` that was passed in.  This makes it so that `this.SomeList1` points to the same list instance as the code that passed it to the constructor.

Since they're pointing to the same list instances, you can update them as you see fit in the calling code, and the adapter will be none the wiser.  Calling `notifyDataSetChanged` after changes were made will cause the adapter to refresh itself.  This causes `getItemCount` to be re-evaluated.  Since the lists are now updated, you'll get the updated count.

```
// Initialize adapter. Empty lists.
List<Class1> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
List<Class2> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
PrefAdapter adapter = new PrefAdapter(context, list1, list2);

// Set adapter on recycler view.
...

// Update lists. First list has 1 item, second list has 2.
list1.add(new Class1());
list2.add(new Class2());
list2.add(new Class2());

// Notify adapter that data has changed.
// This causes the adapter to refresh itself.
// Since the list instances are the same,
// when getItemCount is re-evaluated, it will return 3.

adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: That would work, but what about that `count` hack? The count variable doesn't reinitialize, it just takes off from where it left off, when I call `notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: Looks like you answered your own question.  I have to admit, I didn't notice the 'hack' you had in there until you just mentioned it. I'm glad you figured it out though.  Congrats.

Comment: Thanks! It was really silly of me to make that count variable.